# TFS project working simultaneously on two branches

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

we have a .net framework 1.1 project deploy on production server.
we want to migrate it to .net framework 4.
1 team will continue to fix bugs on the .net1.1 with VS2003 and other team will work on migrating to .net4 with VS2010.
at some point in the future the 2 teams need to merge their changes.
we want that the next version to production will be in .net framework 4.

what is the prefer way to do this in TFS aspects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you make a release branch of the existing version and migrate your trunk (base) to .Net 4. Merge every change in the release branch to the trunk. Changes to plain code files won't be a problem, changes to generated and project files will have to be made manually in the trunk.

Comment: can you give more details, how many branches do i need,what tfs commands, what tfs commands .net1.1 developer will do and what .net4 developer will do, does it matter if .net1.1 will work on the base and .net4 on a new branch?

Comment: You will need only one branch (from your trunk). You can do this in Visual Studio, no commands needed. After that each dev has to work on his own branch, and one of the two will have to do the merging.

Comment: does it matter if the trunk will continue to be for .net1.1 untill we merge the .net4 changes from it branch to the trunk? what is better?

Answer (score 0):

Further to Gerrie's answer, you could take this one step further and strike a release branch for your current production code, and then create two branches.

One branch which will continue as a 1.1 branch for continued development, the other can be upgrade to 4.

Any changes made in the 1.1 branch should be merged up to the trunk and back down to the 4 branch, so that at anytime in the future you can push your 4 branch up to the trunk.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522775/branching-and-merging-strategies) for more information